# How to add link to the matching string of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, text

I have got the list of elements:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#link1">Text link 1</a>
    <span>My text contains text: Text link 1, that's it.</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link2">Text link 2</a>
    <span>My text contains text: Text link 2, that's it.</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link3">Text link 3</a>
    <span>My text contains text: Text link 3, that's it.</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link4">Text link 4</a>
    <span>My text contains text: Text link 4, that's it.</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to have something like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#link1">Text link 1</a>
    <span>My text contains text: <a href="#link1">Text link 1</a>, that's it.</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link2">Text link 2</a>
    <span>My text contains text: <a href="#link1">Text link 2</a>, that's it.</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link3">Text link 3</a>
    <span>My text contains text: <a href="#link1">Text link 3</a>, that's it.</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#link4">Text link 4</a>
    <span>My text contains text: <a href="#link4">Text link 4</a>, that's it.</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to wrap the string in span which match with a link above it in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQAPK/91/)

```
$("li").each(function() {
var getanchirlink = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
$(this).find('span').html($(this).find('span').html().replace(/Text link [0-9]/g,'<a href='+getanchirlink+'>'+$(this).find('a').html()+'</a>'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
        var link=$(this).find('a').attr('href');
        var txtlink=$(this).find('a').text();

        var span=$(this).find('span');

        var rep='<a href="'+link+'">'+txtlink+'</a>';
        var txtspan=span.text();
        var nSpan=txtspan.replace(txtlink,rep);
        span.html(nSpan);
    });
});
```

try with this... it's work for me.